# graphql: Must provide Source. Received: {kind: "Document, definition ...}

Tags: node.js, graphql, resolver

I'm really new to Graphql (just yesterday actually). I am "playing" around and try the various tools of the ecosystem (apollo-server, graphql.js ...ect).

For the sake of experimenting, I am trying to call a query from within nodejs (and not from a client in the browser, such as a react application)

First of all this is my simple schema along with resolvers:

```
export const mySchema = gql`
   type User {
      id: ID!
      name:  
      surname: String
   }

   # root query has been defined in another file
   extend type Query {
      users: [User]
      test: [User]
   }
` 
export const myResolvers = {
   users: () => [ __array_of_users__ ],
   test: () => /* this is where I would like to re-invoke the 'users query'
}
```

Using the `makeExecutableSchema` function, I create a `schema` object with my types and my resolvers and I export this schema into the apollo server application. Every thing works fine so far.

Now following this [stackoverflow suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424728/how-to-execute-graphql-query-from-server), I created a helper function which should allow me to invoke a query defined in my schema as following:

```
import { graphql } from "graphql";
import { schema } from "./my-schema";

export const execute = str => {
  return graphql(schema, str );
};
```

With this helper function, my resolvers become:

```
import { gql } from "apollo-server-express";
import { execute } from '__path_to_helper_function__';

export const myResolvers = {
  users: () => [ __array_of_users__ ],
  test:  () => execute( gql`
     query users {
           name
      }    
  `)
}
```

But in the playground, when I try the query:

```
   {
      test {
        name
      }
   }
```

I get the following error:

[image]

I don't even know if what I am trying to do (to call a query from within node) can be done. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thnaks

Answer (score 1):

`graphql-tag` takes a string and parses it into a `DocumentNode` object. This is effectively the same as passing a String to the `parse` function. Some functions exported by the `graphql` module, like `execute`, expect to be passed in a `DocumentNode` object -- the `graphql` function does not. It should be passed just a plain String as the request, as you can see from the signature:

```
graphql(
  schema: GraphQLSchema,
  requestString: string,
  rootValue?: ?any,
  contextValue?: ?any,
  variableValues?: ?{[key: string]: any},
  operationName?: ?string
): Promise<GraphQLResult>
```

So, just drop the `gql` tag. You can see an (incomplete) API reference [here](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/graphql/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I removed the 'gql' as suggested and pass now a string: ' query users { name } '.
I now get the error: 
"Cannot query field "name" on type "Query"." 
What could this error mean?

Comment: You are requesting the field `name` on the root query type, which doesn't exist. Presumably you meant `query { users { name } }`. The former still works because `users` is just treated as the name of the operation.

Comment: I tried your suggestion `query { users { name } }`, unfortunately I am getting the same error...

Comment: @TheSoul Are you getting the *same* error as before? `Cannot query field "name" on type "Query"`

Comment: Either way, this should probably be a separate question with all relevant code. The error you are seeing is unrelated to your original issue.